# Let $A \in \mathbb{M_n(F)}$. Every polynomial$(p)$ of degree n such that $p(A)=0$ then how $p$ can be expressed?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{M_n(F)}$. If polynomial$(p)$ of degree n such that $p(A)=0$ then, how $p$ can be expressed? where $\mathbb{F}$ = $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Here is my way of approach...

Let $p_A, m_A$ are characteristic and minimal polynomials.

Suppose $deg(m_A)<n$ polynomial p may be $\alpha p_A + \beta m_A$ for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}$. Since $\alpha p_A + \beta m_A$ is $n^{th}$ degree polynomial.

and now $deg(m_A)=n$, choose $\beta =0$ then $p$ is $\alpha p_A$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$.

(Is there any other $p$'s out of $\alpha p_A + \beta m_A$ such that p(A)=0?)

Answer (score 1):

By definition, polynomials that satisfy $p(A)=0$ are exactly those divisible by $m_A$.

So what you can say is that $p = fm_A$ for some polynomial $f$ that has degree $n-\deg(m_A)$.

Comment: I agree with you. but my intention is to express $p$ in $p_A $ and $m_A$. so  does $\alpha p_A + \beta m_A$ cover all p's ? in your language, does every $fm_A$ can be expressed as $\alpha p_A + \beta m_A$?

Comment: Heuristically : look at how many degrees of liberty you have for choosing $f$, and how many degrees of liberty you have for $\alpha p_A + \beta m_A$.